# How to open incognito(private) window in protractor

Tags: protractor

I have a application like gmail.So when user logged out,it save the username and when next user try to login,it shows the password page instead of username page(because every actions occurs in one window itself).So i need to open private(incognito) window for each user.I have a user loop for login and i tried to open the private window as given below.

```
var i;  
for(i=0; i<user_count; i++){          
   element(by.css(".username")).sendKeys(test@gmail.com);
   ....
   ....
   element(by.css(".logout")).click();
   browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, protractor.Key.SHIFT ,"n")).perform();
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){
          browser.switchTo.window(handles[1]); 
          browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
          element(by.linkText(locators.locator_signinBtn)).click();
        });
}
```

But the above code not opening the new private window.How can we do this.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `browser.restart();` in your loop. And to open your chrome in  incognito mode update the chrome options as below

```
capabilities: {
    'directConnect': true,
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ["--incognito"]
    }
},
```

Comment: Great thanks madhan..But when i am opening the browser second time by browser.restart(), the functions in onPrepare is not accessible to secondly opened browser.my onPrepare function is given below.
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    global.testdata = require('./support/testdata.js');
}
So how can i access these, in each time when i open the browser.